# Hibernate not working 14.04

Tags: hibernate

I searched everywhere and while there are guides none say what to do if a step wont work, so this isn't a duplicate as far as I know. If it is I'll take this down but PLEASE read the full question first.

I used [this guide](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/).

So I do `sudo pm-hibernate` and then my screen goes to the hibernate screen say:

> snap-shoting
>   snapshot done
>   writing(or something like that)____0%

and then hangs there forever. My swap is seen and is 9GB, I have 6GB RAM. It is a dual boot with Windows 7.

Answer (score 8):

To know your swap partition, run `swapon -s`.  Let's say it reports `/dev/sda6`.

Open `/etc/default/grub` and find the line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`.  This is the list of kernel command line options GRUB will pass to Linux.  Add `resume=/dev/sda6`, so the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash enable_mtrr_cleanup=1"
```

will now look like this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash enable_mtrr_cleanup=1 resume=/dev/sda6"
```

Save the file and run this to enable the new configuration:

```
sudo update-grub2
```